# CSS font embedding

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-family

I'm just curious about embedding fonts that are standard fonts. I mean do I really need to embed external (`TTF`) font file to make it work on all browsers?

For example, I'd like to use `Times New Roman` font which is really well-known and is very common, should I also use `@font-face` and embed `TTF` file of Times New Roman to make it work on all browsers?

Thank you in advance for the information you can provide me.

Comment: If a font exists on the computer then it will be used, if not then it will look for the other fonts in your font-family declaration as a fall back.  You can use the @font-face to ensure every computer will have a copy of the font.  [Have a read of this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family).  Ps embedding a ttf only won't work on all browsers, you would also need the .woff, .eot and .svg versions of the font

Answer (score 2):

There are no standard fonts. There is not a single font that is available in all devices; for example, many mobile devices have just a few fonts, and those fonts are normally not available in desktop devices.

Besides, even if a font with the name Times New Roman, for example, exists in different devices, it need not be the same. They might come from different manufacturers, or they might be different versions (mostly so that newer versions have a larger character repertoire, but other differences are possible, too).

Thus, the only way to have a particular font used in all devices, to the extent it is possible at all, is to embed it. Whether you specify a local font as the primary option is a different issue, and not always feasible. Most of the fonts that are commonly available in Windows PC’s, for example, are not free fonts; it may be impossible to embed them legally, or embedding them may require a permission, for a fee.

Answer (score 0):

No, for the most standard fonts, you don't need to include an external ttf.
Some typical combinations used for font-family you can see here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

It's always recommended to use a whole font-family as a fallback for the case that other fonts couldn't be loaded. Also note, that font names using multiple words have to be enclosed into quotation marks